# Possible to log all package

Tags: spring, logging, spring-boot

This is my ***application.properties***:

```
logging.level.root= WARN
logging.level.org.springframework.web=INFO
logging.level.com.app.test.security=DEBUG
logging.level.com.app.test.service=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate=ERROR
logging.file=logs/spring-boot-logging.log
logging.pattern.console= %d{yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level [%thread] %logger{15} - %msg%n
```

i want to know if it's possible to define a `logging.level` for all pacakge like this:

```
logging.level.com.app.test.*=DEBUG
```

Answer (score 1):

`logging.level.com.app.test=DEBUG` works like how you want.

All classes **and** packages under `com.app.test` will have a DEBUG log level.